# Removing references to Java object in JPype

Tags: java, python-2.7, memory, null, jpype

I am trying to destroy a Java object in JPype in order for garbage collection to manage the heap space, at the moment the heap space usage just keeps growing until an out of memory error is thrown.
I am re-allocating the object name inside a loop, and the heap memory is sufficient for handling any specific execution of loop iteration.

What is the proper way of assigning `null` to a Java object in JPype?

I have tried `foo = None` and `del foo` in the hope that these will remove the references as needed in the Java Virtual Machine, but to no avail.

Edit:

I have isolated the offending lines. I am repeatedly calling

`bar = jpype.JArray(jpype.JDouble, 1)(foo)`

and each call seems to create an unreferenced double that is not deleted.

I have confirmed that the memory leak involves unreferenced doubles that are not deleted by analysing a memory dump.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do any other references exist to the object you're trying to get rid of?

Comment: Eclipse Memory Analyzer on a heap dump indicates that the heap is filling up with unreachable `double[]` objects, about one for every time the loop executed before throwing the Out of Memory error.

Comment: For this specific case, the memory leak does not occur when running on OSX, but does occur in Windows 7.